# Symfony2.1 and AdvancedUserInterface: customization of the login error messages from UserChecker

Tags: exception, symfony, authentication, symfony-2.1

How to customize in a **Symfony2.1** app the error messages provided by the *[UserChecker](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserChecker.html)* class when using an *User* class that implements *[AdvancedUserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.html)*?

These messages are provided for instance when user is not enabled or its account has been locked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it even in Symfony 2.0 easily.

There is no need to reimplement the `UserCheckerInterface`.

Implement the login form as described here: [Using a Traditional Login Form](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form).

`$error` is actually an instance of [AuthenticationException](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/AuthenticationException.html).

If you display it in the template like this:

```
{% if error %}{{ error.message|trans }}{% endif %}
```

... then you can customize the messages using the translation component, ex. in your **messages.en.yml**:

```
'User account is locked.': 'Your account has been locked by administrator.'
'The presented password is invalid.': 'Invalid password.'
'Bad credentials': 'Invalid username.'
```

If you do that you get translations for free :)

BTW I've read a case study that suggested that specyfing to the user what exactly went wrong with the login (pass? username?) outweighs the security issues (in terms of UX) and greatly improves the conversion (returning users).

Comment: I'd prefer *not* to tell a potential attacker whether or not the user exists in the database vs an incorrect password. I'll just tell them that they didn't match, and that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in Symfony 2.1. It is scheduled to be released as part of Symfony 2.2

See this [discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/4935) for more information.

---

Updated in response to @JeanValjean

You can implement the [Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserCheckerInterface.html)

And then use the following configuration key to set the user checker to your class.

```
security.user_checker.class = My\User\Checker\Class.
```

Comment: Apart from the feature, are you sure that one cannot hack the official components (e.g. by replacing such a service)?

Comment: I'll try this solution in a couple of days! Keep in touch.